# Create css source map files with mindscape workbench

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, sass, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I've been looking around trying to find a solution to Sass development in an environment that includes an ASP.NET MVC webserver developed in VS 2012. We are using web workbench for Sass compilation - and here's the problem:

When workbench compiles an SCSS file, if the "debug" flag is set to on, it creates a css file with mappings in it.

Chrome dev tools "experiment", which is a commonly used method for Sass debugging, expects a standalone map file (*.css.map). The difference originates from the fact that the latest workbench uses Sass 3.2.9, while source map files have been introduced in sass 3.3.

Does anyone have any experience with this matter? 
I'd think there are a few ways to go here

1. Somehow modify workbench
2. somehow downgrade chrome to an earlier version that worked with inline mapping
3. Create the files in another way, not relying on workbench
4. Losing workbench altogether for another alternative (which?)

Any inputs will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: did you resolve this?